# Force reset of login details for Facebook online account

Tags: empathy, facebook, telepathy

Earlier this week I had to reset my Facebook password.  Online Accounts requested me to grant access with the new login details; I mis-typed the new password several times, and got redirected to a secondary authorization page where I finally typed it correctly. Since then Empathy has been unable to connect to Facebook, and in fact telepathy-gabble has been crashing as a result.

I reset my Facebook password again, but this time did not even receive an authorization request from within Online Accounts/Empathy.  I've also tried editing the password manually in the Gnome keyring.  However, Empathy simply will not connect to Facebook any more (though there are no more telepathy-gabble crashes).

Is there any way to force Online Accounts to require me to re-authorize the account?  Or any way, short of deleting the account, of fixing the current failure to log in?

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: Can you provide us which Ubuntu version you're using?

Comment: Whoops!  What an oversight.  It's 13.04 -- I've updated the original question too.

Comment: Enjoy -- http://askubuntu.com/questions/344239/empathy-facebook-account-requires-authorization-problem/384481#384481