# empathy "Facebook account requires authorization" problem

Tags: empathy, facebook

I am trying to connect to my Facebook account from Empathy on Ubuntu 13.04.

When setting up the account in Empathy everything looks OK, but then Empathy just shows the message:

> Facebook account requires authorization

According to [bug #1170832](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1170832), this is due to a problem in the telepathy-gabble package which has been fixed in version 0.18.1.

However, I manually installed `telepathy-gabble_0.18.1-1_amd64.deb` from [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/telepathy-gabble/0.18.1-1/+build/4951723) and the problem persists. Has anyone else had any luck with this?

Answer (score 9):

The telepathy-gabble 0.18.1 package in Ubuntu actually contained a work-around for the problem, not a proper solution. Quoting from the [ChangeLog](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/telepathy-gabble/+changelog):

```
telepathy-gabble (0.18.1-1) unstable; urgency=low

  * New upstream stable release
    - work around Facebook server behaviour change so we don't consider its
      service discovery response to be spoofed (Closes: #721883)

 -- Simon McVittie  Mon, 09 Sep 2013 13:05:13 +0100
```

Apparently, this work-around does not work, and in fact the status of the bug has been reverted from *Fix Released* to *Confirmed*.

For the proper fix I'm sorry you will have to wait for the [upstream bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=68829) to be fixed (unless someone proposes an another work-around in the meantime).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and been looking at the suggestions.

On Ubuntu 13.10

What worked for me:

1. Removed fb account from online account in settings.
2. Went to fb on firefox and the little gear>account settings>apps>removed access of ubuntu.
3. Re-entered fb account on online accounts on desktop this time using the fb "username" only **NOT** the email address.

That worked for me.

Hope this helps.

-Owie

Answer (score -1):

Just a couple suggestions you might try...

**No-1.** Log into facebook and turn off notifications for log-ins...
**`Facebook > Account Settings > Account Security (change) >
Change "Would you like to receive notifications for logins from new devices?" to NO.`**

**No-2.** Try logging out of facebook and logging back in (with the **`"facebook username"`**, not email)

More suggestion and info here → http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1487433

Hope this helps... Good Luck!

Comment: Yeah I tried that already, did it work for you ?

Comment: Didn't work for me